# In iOS, why objRect can be used but NSLog(@"%@", objRect) will cause bad memory access?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, nslog

In iOS, `objRect` is a `CGRect` object.  The code runs fine with

```
if (objRect.origin.x > 0)  { 
    // do something 
}
```

but under it, the line

```
NSLog(@"%@", objRect);
```

will cause bad memory access (`EXC_BAD_ACCESS`) and the program will stop.  Why is that?  Can the object be printed out otherwise?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CGRect is not an Objective-C object, so it cannot respond to [objRect description] (which is what %@ means). It is a structure:

```
struct CGRect {
    CGPoint origin;
    CGSize size;
};
typedef struct CGRect CGRect;
```

If you want to log your CGRect, you can use [NSStringFromCGRect](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIKitFunctionReference/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/NSStringFromCGRect).